# How to get latitude longitude from current location using CLLocationManager in swift?

Tags: swift3, cllocationmanager

I am new to `Swift` and I want to get `latitude & longitude` from the current location. Using those `latitude & longitude` auto fill the `UITextField` by getting city & country name on UITextField in `Swift-3`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.getCurrentAddress { currentAddress, error in
            if let address = currentAddress, let city = address["City"] as? String, let country = address["Country"] as? String  {
                self.txtField.text = "\(city), \(country)"
            }
        }
    }

    func getCurrentAddress(completion: @escaping (_ currentAddress: [String:Any]?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
        var currentLocation: CLLocation!
        let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if authStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse || authStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways {
            currentLocation = locationManager.location
            let longi = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
            let lat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
            let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
            geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation) { placemarks, error in
                if let e = error {
                    completion(nil, e)
                } else {
                    let placeArray = placemarks
                    let placeMark = (placeArray?[0])!

                    guard let currentAddress = placeMark.addressDictionary as? [String:Any] else {
                        return
                    }
                    completion(currentAddress, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Need to set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in your plist file

Comment: i will try @Vini App and will let u know

Comment: where i will get the lat long using above code @Vini App

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: i will check ur updated answer and let u know @Vini App

Comment: used ur code but app crashes at this line "let longi = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude" @Vini App

Comment: the above is code is working. Can you please post some sample code how you are using `currentLocation` and `longitude`